# Does order of characters in character class matter in regular expressions

Tags: java

I was using character class in regular expression to split a string. I had an assumption that order of characters in the character class does not matter.

Following are the two patterns I was using to split the string `"123.3+23+23.3"`.

```
[+/*-]

[+*-/]
```

For the first pattern I got the output as:

```
123.3
23
23.3
```

For the second pattern I got the output as :

```
123
3
23
23
3
```

I've no idea, why I am getting the different outputs. Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within a character class, `-` is a range operator (as in `[a-f]` is the same as `[abcdef]`). So if you want to include an actual `-` in your range, it must be the first or last character.

Therefore, your first example will match `+` `/` `*` `-`, while your second will match `+` `/` `*` `-` `,` `.`.

[image]

Comment: `-` doesn't have to be first or last, you can also escape it: `"[+*\\-/]"`

Comment: Sure, but if you don't escape it then it will act as a range unless it is the first or last character in the character class. Still good to point out, though.

Comment: @Andreas Isn't a single backslash enough?

Comment: @cst1992 Not in a Java literal. The `-` needs to be ``\`` escaped for the regex parser, so the escape needs to be doubled for the Java parser.